# Figuring out how to output data the right way for a chart to work

Tags: cakephp, highcharts, google-visualization

I've been trying to figure out a way to get data from my database, and then display it in a way that a a chart can read it.

Controller:
        $this->Record->virtualFields['sum'] ='COUNT(*)';

```
    $records=$this->Record->find('list', 
        array('fields' => array('drug_id', 'sum'), // from the table 'drugs' with 2 fields which drug_id and drug
            'group'  => 'drug_id'));
    debug($records);
    $chartData[] = implode(', ',$records);
    debug($chartData);
```

How my 'debugs' display on the page:

```
/app/Controller/RecordsController.php (line 72)
array(
'Trees' => '2',
'Socks' => '1',
'Things' => '9',
'Mice' => '1',
'Clothes' => '6',
'Shoes' => '4',
'Underwear' => '3',
'Tables' => '6',
'Mouse' => '1'
)
/app/Controller/RecordsController.php (line 74)
array(
(int) 0 => '2, 1, 9, 1, 6, 4, 3, 6, 1'
)
```

As you can see, the impload, for some reason, removes the substance field. I need it to display like this:

```
'Underwear', '1'
etc
```

EDIT:

How would I use hasMany to assign the compound an id with the database. Because the same compound will have many different users. And many different compounds will have the same users.

I'm reading the documentation, but I don't know if i'm missing something but it seems like it just randomly cuts out on the documentation... it seems like it just tells you what it does and how to start it.

If I were to run the query right now (i edited the query above for this example) I will get values with

```
'5' => '2'
```

But I would need to, I assume, use hasMany to associate what will be in my database

```
ID | Compound
5  | Tables
```

So that I can display 'tables' instead of 5

Comment: Can you show how are you passing that array to google chart?

Comment: After my initial code,

    $this->set('output',$records);

then I just echo the output variable in my view. I also tried imploding the data by a comma, which would simply leave me with the sum values but not the substance values for some reason

Comment: So you are trying to output/implode a php variable on a js script? Or just printing it in you're view and hope for the best? Update your question with the exact code of that view your outputting the variable to. There's the error, so without looking at it it will be difficult to help.

Comment: Thanks for the response, I updated the original post with the full code I use and the output I get.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think you are quite a bit confused. Lets take it step by step.

First, `implode` concatenates the values of the array, not the keys, so it's logical you get that output, it's not "for some reason". Read [the docs](http://php.net/manual/en/function.implode.php) about that function, is very helpful to know what it does.

Second... well, from what I see, you're trying to mix php variables with js. It's "possible", but you need to really understand what you're doing. Google Charts or Highcharts construct graphs with js, at least based on the output you want to have. It's weird that you're imploding a variable in the controller and print it *just like that* in the view.

So, pass the `$records` variable to the view as is. Do not try to transform it to an js-adequate-structure in the controller. Why? Because you can use `$records` in any part of your view (as a php variable), and output the necessary structure just in the js part.

Now, the graph. Let's say you're using Google charts because that's the first example I found. Somewhere in your view, you should have something similar to this

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    //definitions of your chart, I'm not going to do that here

    //the data part
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addRows([
      ['Mushrooms', 3],
      ['Onions', 1],
      ['Olives', 1],
    ]);
```

That's the data you want to "translate" from php-find-variable to js, right? For that you can do something like this

```
    //the data part
    var data = new google.visualization.DataTable();
    data.addRows([
      <?php
          foreach($records as $compound => $sum)
             echo "['".$compound."', ".$sum."], ";
       ?>
    ]);
```

And you should have the js format you need. Check the syntax, though, I didn't test it so maybe there's a comma or something you need to add to that `echo`.

I hope I made it clear enough. If you're confuse about anything here, I recommend to read about using php variables in js.

Comment: I just... don't know how to thank you.

That fixed it instantly, on the first try, even after i've spent almost 3 days researching it and trying to figure it out. THANK YOU.

Yes I was extremely confused, because this was one of my first projects that had to do with php/js working together. I learned a lot from your response.

Thanks again!

Comment: Very glad to help :) I completely understand your confusion with php-to-js development. For future reference, an echo like that to a `var test` in js or something like that is the way to go. Also, check the `json_encode` [function in php](http://php.net/manual/en/function.json-encode.php), it helps tons.

Comment: I have a very different question but on the same exact project. If you don't mind can you look at it? I'll edit it in the original post. Is asking another question in the same thread against the rules?

Comment: If you have another question, well, first, try searching around. If nothing works you ask another question, don't edit this one, it doesn't matter if it's about the same project. Post all the necessary code for us to help you, with a clear explanation of what you're trying to do, what is the error, and what you've done to try to fix it, and SO users will try to give you a helpful answer :) But do a thorough search first!